# why do you have to define the algorithm in decrypt() if importKey() already has it?

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, webcrypto-api, subtlecrypto

To decrypt something with the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) you have to first import the key thusly:

```js
const result = crypto.subtle.importKey(
    format,
    keyData,
    algorithm,
    extractable,
    usages
);
```

This returns a promise. If you append `.then(function(importedKey) {})` to that you'll be able to use the actual imported key to decrypt:

```js
const result = crypto.subtle.decrypt(algorithm, key, data);
```

My question is...  since the imported key object already has the algorithm specified why do you need to respecify the algorithm when trying to do the actual decryption?

Related to this, [importKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey) seems to support RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 as an algorithm but [decrypt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/decrypt) doesn't. If decrypt() doesn't support RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 then why does importKey?

Comment: RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 is a signature scheme, so not used for encryption.

Comment: @Ry- - good point. I guess I got RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 and RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 confused. In my head I just remember "PKCS1" - I don't remember the bits that come before. My first question still stands tho. If I specify OAEP for `importKey` then why do I need to specify it again for `decrypt`? Seems redundant...